# EXCEL: How to explore if there is a value anf if there is i put 1 otherwise 0

Tags: excel, vlookup

[image]

I have 3 columns with id and I would like to write the history for each id.

I tried to use the function "vlookup" but I did not.

Many thanks

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/T5JCS.png)[2](https://i.stack.imgur.com/T5JCS.png)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

if you want to put only 1 or 0 based on count, try using If formula together with countif formula. 
For example for id 1 in history:
For orientation, the "A" value in id table is cell A2
=if(countif(A3:A7, E3)>0, 1, 0)
Hope it helps!

Comment: It doesn't matter, how many rows. I run similar formulas on 100k rows charts. If it doesn't work, tell me, what happend?

Comment: I would be grateful if you would write to me again the function according to the second photo. Thanks for all.

Comment: for the cell you are in "=if(countif(A:A, G7)>0, 1, 0)"